# Windows 7 uses always IPC$ as path when connecting to a samba share

Tags: windows, samba, share, ipc

I have a smb share : \mysmb\www

When connection from Windows XP all runs fine. When connecting from Windows 7 I got an error like 'wrong password'.

In smbd log I can see :

```
  Invalid username/password for [IPC$]
```

I think this means that Windows7 always trys to access IPC$ instead of www. Windows XP uses -correctly -  www as share name.

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Thorsten

Answer (score 1):

IPC$ standards for *Inter Process Communication*, the $ sign indicates it is hidden. The IPC$ share is used for all kinds of non-filesystem operations, like account management, printing, etc.

Windows 7 is probably doing some other operation first (getting more information about the user?) before it tries to open the www share. The fact that is uses IPC$ isn't wrong, although admittedly confusing.

Comment: thanks. seems that I have to configure access to IPC$ separately. will give feedback on this

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct password and you shouldn't get a "wrong password" error. Windows 7 is connecting to IPC$ *before* connecting to WWW. Once the connection is working correctly, Windows 7 will go on to access the resource you requested.

Comment: I'm using the same credentials from windows7 and windows XP

Comment: @thorsten: I believe you may be entering the same username and password, but the OS is likely trying to authenticate differently.

Comment: have investigated it using wireshark. yes! windows xp uses DOMAIN\user Windows 7 uses \user. But there are other differences in communication too - especially in Session Setup AndX Requests